# wordpress specified nav menu container class different

Tags: wordpress

static html code like below

```
<div class="color1 navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="color2 navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use wp_nav_menu() get menu items which set via admin panel and every div container include 6 items.
I'm not familiar with wp,so need you point how to loop.
Thank you.

//
I found a way and runs well.

```
  $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menus[0]);

  $i = 1;

  $total = count($menu_items);

  $menuBox = ceil($total/6);
  foreach ($menu_items as $key=>$menu_item):
    if ($key%6==0) {
      echo '<div class="color'.$i.' grid_6 navbox"><ul>';
      $i++;
    }
    echo "<li> <a href='$menu_item->url'>$menu_item->title</a></li>";

    if ($key== $total-1) {
      echo '</ul></div>';
    }else{
      for ($j=0; $j < $menuBox; $j++) {
        if ($key == $j*6-1) {
           echo '</ul></div>';
        }
      }
    }
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. The best way to do it is to declare custom navigation locations, then call them where they are needed (this avoids duplicate IDs if you decide to use the same nav in more than one place on a page).

This would go in your functions file (change the names as needed):

```
function nav_menu_locations() {
  // Register nav menu locations
  register_nav_menus( array(
    'header' => 'Header Menu',
    'sidebar' => 'Sidebar Menu',
    'footer' => 'Footer Menu'
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nav_menu_locations' );
```

Then to call one of them, use this in the appropriate template:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header')); ?>
```